# PowerShell - How do I bulk upload Certificates to an Azure App Registration Certificate store?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, certificate, powershell-az-module

As you can see from the code below I can upload on certificate at a time, but the problem is it wipes out all of the existing certificates when doing so.

```
$Tenant_ID = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
$Subscription_ID = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
$Azure_PassWord = (Get-StoredCredential -Target 'Domain' -Type Generic -AsCredentialObject).Password
$UserName = "$($env:USERNAME)@Google.com"
$EncryptedPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $Azure_PassWord -AsPlainText -Force
$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential($UserName,$EncryptedPassword)
$AzureConnection = (Connect-AzAccount -Credential $Credential -Tenant $Tenant_ID -Subscription $Subscription_ID -WarningAction 'Ignore').context 
$AzureContext = (Set-AzContext -SubscriptionName $Subscription_ID -DefaultProfile $AzureConnection) 
$Application_ID = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'

$PFX_FileName = "Azure_Dev_V2"
$Cert_Password = "123456"
$Cert_Password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $Cert_Password -Force -AsPlainText
$CurrentDate = Get-Date
$EndDate = $CurrentDate.AddYears(10)

$certificatePath =  "C:\FilePath\Certificates\Certs\$($PFX_FileName).pfx" # OR Get-ChildItem -Path cert:\localmachine\my\$($Certificate_Thumbprint)
$cert = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2($certificatePath, $Cert_Password)
$keyValue = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($cert.GetRawCertData())
$Azure_App_Registration = Get-AzADApplication -ApplicationId $Application_ID -DefaultProfile $AzureContext

New-AzADAppCredential -ApplicationObject $Azure_App_Registration -CertValue $keyValue -EndDate $EndDate -StartDate $CurrentDate 

Connect-AzAccount -Subscription $Subscription_ID -ApplicationId $Azure_App_Registration.AppId -Tenant $Tenant_ID -CertificateThumbprint $cert.Thumbprint | Out-Null

Get-AzADAppCredential -ApplicationId $Azure_App_Registration.AppId | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -match "CN=Azure_Dev_V2"}
```

In the Azure portal multiple certificates can be uploaded manually, and they will not delete the existing certificates.

EDIT: If bulk upload is not possible then how would I go about making sure the existing certificates that are in the Azure AD App Registration cert store do not get deleted ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I'd suggest using Microsoft Graph for this (there is a Powershell module available)

Comment: The PS module can be searched as `MS Graph PowerShell SDK`, or installed with `Install-Module Microsoft.Graph`. Note - I ran your code and found no issues uploading multiple certificates one-by-one, even uploading the same certificate twice

Comment: @scottwtang yeah I finally found the module, waiting for access to try it. Could you provide and example on how you accomplished ("no issues uploading multiple certificates one-by-one, even uploading the same certificate twice") as I can upload the same one again but it deletes and over writes all of the other certificates.